# Does a parameterized return type require a generic method signature?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, types, emgucv

Specifically, I'm working with [EmguCV's `Image` type](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/a8929aab-99c5-79cf-385c-dcec7769fea1.htm).

I've defined an interface `ITransformation` with a method `ApplyFrom` that takes an `Image` and returns an `Image`:

```
public interface ITransformation
{
    Image<TColor, TDepth> ApplyFrom<TColor, TDepth>(Image<TColor, TDepth> sourceImage);
}
```

But this seems awfully verbose with type parameters, especially when that method gets used.  Ideally, the interface would look like this:

```
public interface ITransformation
{
    Image ApplyFrom(Image sourceImage);
}
```

But Visual Studio complains about `Image` requiring 2 type parameters.  I don't want to bind the `ApplyFrom()` method to a specific color or depth

**Do I *need* to use the generic, verbose first version above?**

**Or am I missing some possible middle ground between the two versions?**

Comment: Could you get by with using the `IImage` interface instead?

Comment: @juharr, that's a great idea.  I will be able to do that in other places, but not here.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to use the generic, verbose first version above?

Yes - you need to specify generic parameters when referring to a generic type.  Just like you can't reference `List` as a type - you need to fully qualify the generic parameter (`List<T>`, `List<int>`, etc.)

The compiler *may* be able to infer generic parameters when *using* the method, but the declaration must include the generic parameters in all three positions that you have them.

About the only thing you can do to reduce the verbosity (and still keep the function generic) is to shorten the generic parameter names:

```
public interface ITransformation
{
    Image<C, D> ApplyFrom<C, D>(Image<C, D> sourceImage);
}
```

You lose the self-documenting nature of the generic parameters, but to the compiler there is no difference.

Comment: I accept my fate.  Thanks for the detailed explanation!  I'm pretty impressed by the StackOverflow C# community.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to bind the ApplyFrom() method to a specific color or depth

That's exactly what generics are for.  It's for writing a method that doesn't require those types that are generic to be specified when writing this method.

Those are your choices; specify the exact types used by the images, without allowing them to ever be anything else, or make the method generic, so that the caller can provide an image with any types that it wants as the generic arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the method shorter, but at the cost of making the interface generic (and thus more verbose).

```
public interface ITransformation<T, TColor, TDepth> where T : Image<TColor, TDepth> {
    T ApplyFrom(T sourceImage);
}
```

Comment: Great alternative.  I've never seen that `where` clause before.  What does it do?

Comment: ['where'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) makes sure the `ITransformation` is only called for your Images (and not for Strings for example). If you don't need that, you can even get away with   `public interface ITransformation<T> {
   T ApplyFrom(T sourceImage);
  }`

Comment: Note that this option prevents the use of generic type inference.

Comment: @Glorfindel, ah, I think I see.  So in Java, the analogous feature is the generic constraint syntax that looks like this:  `method(List<T extends SomeType>)`.  Right?

Comment: It is related, but not analogous. It's hard to explain the difference in a comment, though.